# Stuck on the cancellation of sums when calculating sample variance estimates

Tags: statistics

I'm looking at how the sample variance is an unbiased estimate when divided by n-1, as opposed to just "n", and in doing so have the following part of the proof outlined:

$$E(S^2)=E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2}}{n-1}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\left(X_i-\mu\right)-\left(\bar{X}-\mu\right)\right)^2}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\left(X_i-\mu\right)^2-2\left(X_i-\mu\right)\left(\bar{X}-\mu\right)+\left(\bar{X}-\mu\right)^2\right)}\right]$$

The move from this step to the next one (below) is the confusing bit for me. Where is the logic in how the center term is cancelled in this way?

$$=\frac{1}{n-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\left(X_i-\mu\right)^2-\left(\bar{X}-\mu\right)^2\right)}\right]$$

From here, taking the sums and expectations of each component gives us the variances of the samples, that cancel and result in the expected population variance when n-1 is used, but this step above is what's killing me, and I'm pretty sure its some trivial matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I believe what's happening is that $E(X_i - \mu)$ is becoming $E(\bar{X} - \mu)$ in the middle term of the expectation, so that when you add the last term you are left with an overall contribution of $-(\bar{X} - \mu)^2$.

Comment: From the final result it would have to be that by taking the component sum or expectation that term becomes $(\bar{X}-\mu)$ but I'm not seeing the mechanics of it and how it works out that this is the case.

Comment: Ahh! I see what's happening. By taking the expectation of the terms of the sum, we get $E(X_i-\mu)$ as you mentioned, but then we can take this a step further to $E(X_i)-E(\mu)$, and then because $E(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ip_i} = \bar{X}$, we end up with $(\bar{X}-\mu)$